# Name This Movie

Tags: movies

This movie was released in 2014, its about "E.T" or in the movie, "Eee Tee"

The main star is a [Youtuber](http://www.youtube.com/user/JamesNintendoNerd) who reviews bad games.

What's the movie? (Please do not post answer as comment)

Comment: Is this a puzzle? Or a trivia question?

Comment: Sort of puzzle, mostly trivia. There is no stackexchange website for trivia so this is the only place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just trivia, not a puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *[Angry Video Game Nerd: The Movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angry_Video_Game_Nerd:_The_Movie)*

The film was produced in 2014 by [James Rolfe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Rolfe_(filmmaker)), also partner of Cinemassacre.
The plot is about the legendary (actually confirmed) burial of tons of unsold E.T. games of Atari 2600.